# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting journey logs and journal blogs
- helpful travel guidebooks and research resources
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1969).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 27):

[image: Wikivoyage, the free travel guide that anyone can edit]

Comment: Is [wikivoyage](https://www.wikivoyage.org/) much different than [wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/)? I've always used the latter and never heard of the former. Is one more open source/community oriented than the other?

Comment: @drs, it's more complicated than I'm about to present, but essentially wikitravel was commercial, and the contributors broke off, and wikivoyage gets more updates from the community. It's also under the umbrella of the wiki foundation now.

Comment: @drs: Yes, the community has moved to WV. That's because WT got bought by a company that did not invest in the project, just placing ads and threatening contributors with lawsuits. WV now surpasses WT by far (even though WT is still a bit higher on Google due to existing backlinks). See how http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo/Roppongi has maps, more illustrations, more details, is more up-to-date, and has less spam than http://wikitravel.org/en/Tokyo/Roppongi

Comment: Thanks for asking @drs and thanks for the answers!

Comment: Now the correct link: [Wikitravel vs Wikivoyage - what's going to be the difference?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/881/2509)  Thanks @drs.  I'm deleting the erroneous comment

Answer (score 16):

[image: Expats.SE]

Comment: The abbreviation *.se* always makes me think I'm looking at an address of a site for expatriates in Sweden.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Current Travel.SE bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/travel.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Answer (score 14):

[image: OsmAnd offline navigation GPS Android app]

Comment: The main strength is that it is usable without Internet

Comment: can you add that somewhere in the Ad? regarding the internet thing

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Added, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This is a great ad - I just saw it active and had to come here to say thanks and +1

Comment: OsmAnd is the best! I used it in Warsaw, London, Madrid, Seoul and Tokyo, it works 100% offline and OpenStreetMaps are of great quality.

Answer (score 11):

[image: The Guide to Hitchhiking the World!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: Why would someone disagree with the twitter account??

Comment: @MarkMayo I downvoted the Twitter ad (and have done so on every other site where I can downvote it) because I think the official SE Twitter accounts are kind of pointless. If you're _already_ on Travel.SE, the Twitter account is useless to you (it just tweets new questions, which you can already see by... well, visiting Travel.SE). On the other hand, many of the external services that have ads here are useful and interesting, and I would prefer to see them be advertised instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect that many users on [Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19015/49701), [Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6841/185694), and [Unix and Linux](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3312/44901) share my view.

Comment: That's a shame, we specifically adjusted ours to use #travel, most commonly noted by travel bloggers / writers, and I know of several who follow it who aren't normally on the site, so it does get some traction :/

Answer (score 9):

[image: Check Passport, Visa & Health travel document requirements via IATA TravelCenter]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Korean Language Area51 proposal]

Comment: Why are people upvoting this?  This has almost nothing to do with travel!

Answer (score 3):

[image: The free world travel guide, in your pocket]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Join our facebook group]

Answer (score 0):

[image: For travelers wondering how cities are built]